# How to apply rejection method?

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $F$ is the cdf of an integer-valued random variable; let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$. Define a random variable $Y=k$ if $F(k-1) \le U < F(k)$. Show that $Y$ has cdf $F$.

And then the question ask me to apply the result to generate geometric r.v. from unif. r.v., but I just want to ask how to show Y has cdf F?

$k-1 \le F^{-1}(U) <k, F(Y)=P(k-1<U<k)=1?$

Comment: There are two formulations of a geometric RV: one counts trials until the first success (so support is positive integers), the other counts trials before the first success (so support is nonnegative integers). The Wikipedia article on geometric RVs shows the CDF, which can be obtained from the standard formula for summing geometric series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cdf of $Y$ is $F$. It is true in general that if $F$ is a cdf and $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then the cdf of the random variable $Y=F^{-1}(U)$ is $F$:

$$P(Y<x)=P(F^{-1}(U)<x)=P(U<F(x))=F(x).$$

For the second part: take the inverse of the cdf of the geometric distribution. The geometric distribution is defined by the following formula:

$$P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1} \ \ k=1,2,\dots$$

The correspondinf cdf is

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0,& \text{ if }&x<1\\
p, &\text{ if }&1\le x<2\\
p+p(1-p), &\text{ if }&2\le x<3\\
\vdots \\
\sum_1^n p(1-p)^{k-1}&\text{ if }&n-1\le x<n\\
\vdots
\end{cases}.$$

Then use the inverse of this cdf. as you did in the OP.

**An illustrative example**

Should there be any problem with the application, please consider my illustrative example. Given the random variable $X$ described by its possible values and the corresponding "masses"
$$X=\begin{cases}
a \text{ with probability }p_1\\
b\text{ with probability }p_2\\
c\text{ with probability }p_3\\
d\text{ with probability }p_4\end{cases}$$

the cdf, $F$, is depicted below.

[image]

Also, $F$'s inverse, $F^{-1}$, is shown. $\color{red}U$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. The right part of the of the figure hints how to select one number from the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ if a realization of $\color{red}U$ is given. Obviously the probability that , say, $b$ occurs equals the length of the corresponding interval. In this case $P(\{b\})=p_1+p_2-p_1=p_2.$

Comment: For the first part, how to apply $Y=k$ if $F(k-1) \le U < F(k)$ ?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the commented question. Yet, I edit my answer according to my guess.

Comment: Please, explain what is unclear. I try to help as much as I can.